# Iterating over columns in pandas with variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
f = {'business':['FX','IR','IR'],'level':['A','A','L'],'amt':[1,2,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f)
df1
```

I have loop that iterates over the columns of the dataframe by creating variables:

```
for business_v,level_v,amt in list(zip(*[df1[col]for col in df1])):
    print (business_v,levelv,amt)
```

Rather than defining three variables `business_v`, `level_v`, and `amt`, is there a way to automatically create variables based on the number of columns in the dataframe `df1`? My dataframe changes in size, and I wanted to create variables based on the size of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating an arbitrary number of variables, you can consider using indexing as follows:

```
for idx in range(df1.shape[0]):
    print ([df1.iloc[i][col] for col in df1.columns()])
```

You can use a custom set of columns instead of calling df1.columns() if you only want to use a subset of columns in the subsequent code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to iterate over rows and don't want to specify variables in for-loop. You can use `.itertuples()` then:

```
for t in df1.itertuples():
    print(t.business, t.level, t.amt)
```

Prints:

```
FX A 1
IR A 2
IR L 3
```

---

Or `.iterrows()`:

```
for idx, t in df1.iterrows():
    print(idx, t[0], t[1], t[2])
```

Prints:

```
0 FX A 1
1 IR A 2
2 IR L 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in df1.itertuples():
    print(i[1],i[2],i[3])
```

---

```
FX A 1
IR A 2
IR L 3
```